# Table doesn't create in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to know why note table doesn't create even there's no error in the code!

Here's my code:

```
 var db = openDatabase("Schedular", "1.0", "schedualar database", 5*1024*1024);
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
     tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE NOTES (NOTE_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NOTE_DATE INTEGER, NOTE_TIME datetime, NOTE_DESC varchar(500),ALERT_TIME INTEGER, NOTES_MORE_DETAILS varchar(1000))",function(tx){},onError);

    });

function onError(tx, error) {
alert("Error Message: "+error.message);

}
```

Here's the code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m3jUd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing a parameter (2nd parameter). It should have an empty array since your not adding any values.

```
interface SQLTransaction {
  void executeSql(in DOMString sqlStatement, in optional ObjectArray arguments, in optional SQLStatementCallback callback, in optional SQLStatementErrorCallback errorCallback);
};
```

Since you wanted a success and error callback, you are missing the arguments array. Something like this should work.

```
var db = openDatabase("Schedular", "1.0", "schedualar database", 5*1024*1024);
db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE NOTES (NOTE_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NOTE_DATE INTEGER, NOTE_TIME datetime, NOTE_DESC varchar(500),ALERT_TIME INTEGER, NOTES_MORE_DETAILS varchar(1000))",[], onSuccess, onError);
});

function onSuccess(tx, rs) {
    alert("Success Message");
}

function onError(tx, error) {
    alert("Error Message: "+ error.message);
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/m3jUd/1/